# Resizing Cufon with Media Queries

Tags: css, cufon, media-queries

Been asked to retrofit a site for smartphones that uses cufon for headings etc.

I'm using media queries to deliver the site. All works ok, but cufon won't resize, despite changes to the relevant css. Pretty sure you do it through the .js, but not a clue how to go about it.

Any ideas or pointers? Thx

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution on another website. Simply add the following:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(window).bind('resize', (function() {
    var timer;
    return function() {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = setTimeout(function() {
        Cufon.refresh();
      }, 50); // possibly more than 50
    };
  })());
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cufon.refresh in the body onResize event. To scale your entire HTML website, see this tutorial.
http://www.peecho.com/blog/scalable-websites-with-css3-and-javascript.html

We use Cufon, too.